# Adobe brackets: write spaces instead of tabs

Tags: indentation, adobe-brackets

I am using brackets with coffeescript, but when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it insert a tabulation whereas i only need **2 spaces**. Also, when I create a line break, **the indent is tabs, and not spaces**. Can I change these 2 setting ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In the lower-right of the status bar you should see an indicator saying "Tab Size." Click the label to toggle to spaces. To change the amount of indent, click the number next to it and type a new value.

Note: if the indicator *already* says "Spaces" then Brackets should be using spaces instead of tab characters already. But it might not *feel* that way because when you move the cursor or press Backspace, there's a "soft tabs" behavior: the cursor will smartly skips over contiguous spaces to line up evenly with the next tab stop. If that bothers you, there will be a [preference](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences) in the next release of Brackets (Sprint 38) to disable that behavior, making the cursor never move more than one space at a time.

Answer (score 20):

For language specific control, Brackets allows you to provide different tab and space indentation values in the `brackets.json` file. For example:

```
"language": {
    "html": {
        "spaceUnits": 4
    },
    "javascript": {
        "tabSize": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely useful. And you can leave a default `"spaceUnits"` outside of `"language": {...}`. Also, I'll put this link here for anyone looking to edit `brackets.json`: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences

Answer (score 0):

For changing tab spacing you can edit your **brackets.json** file. you can find it on **Debug->Open Preferences File** and simple add **"spaceUnits": 2** at the end of the file for 2 space. Remember to add a comma on previous line. You can edit that file for customizing your bracket.
Or you can change it more easily at the right-bottom of your bracket interface you saw a option **Space: 4** click on the number and change it as your wish...